# How do I add a .jar file so I can use it in my IDE (BluJ)

Tags: java, file, jar, symbols

I have a jar file 'BIO.jar' that I want to be able to use in BluJ.

I have copied the .jar file to:

```
/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_60/jre/lib/ext/BIO.jar
```

and

```
/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_60/lib/ext/BIO.jar
```

But I still can't utilise the statement `int y = BIO.getInt();`

BluJ throws me a `cannot find symbol - variable BIO` like it always does.

So, how do I add a .jar file so I can use it in BluJ?

I would assume it's the same process for adding a .jar file to eclipse or netbeans, so, what's the process?

Comment: http://www.bluej.org/faq.html#faq_How_do_I_use_custom_class_libraries__JARs__ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Marged Thank you very much, that answered my question. For anyone wondering the instructions on how to do so are at [bluej.org](http://www.bluej.org/faq.html#faq_How_do_I_use_custom_class_libraries__JARs__).

Remember to check documentation!